# nesting vs not nesting?

Tags: r, mixed-model, lme4-nlme, repeated-measures, random-effects-model

I am following the [tutorial](http://www.bodowinter.com/uploads/1/2/9/3/129362560/bw_lme_tutorial2.pdf) from Bodo Winter.

Bodo created the following model on page 10:

```
politeness <- read.csv("http://www.bodowinter.com/uploads/1/2/9/3/129362560/politeness_data.csv")
lmer(frequency ~ attitude + gender + (1|subject) + (1|scenario), data=politeness)
```

However, it appears that `scenario` is nested within `subject`, so I would use `(1|subject/scenario)` instead. Am I misunderstanding the data/experiment?

Comment: I can't reproduce the example, because the dataset referenced in the doc gives a 404 error. http://www.bodowinter.com/tutorial/politeness_data.csv

Comment: @JeremyMiles I updated my question with the link to the data file.

Comment: I don't see this as a stats question, but don't know the rules for on/off topic here :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to:

```
> xtabs(~ subject + scenario, politeness)

       scenario
subject 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
     F1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2
     F2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2
     F3 2 2 2 2 2 2 2
     M3 2 2 2 2 2 2 2
     M4 2 2 2 2 2 2 2
     M7 2 2 2 2 2 2 2
```

we can see that every level of `subject` appears in every level of `scenario` and vice versa. Thus, with the way the data are coded, these are crossed random effects. So, the model:

```
lmer(frequency ~ attitude + gender + (1|subject) + (1|scenario), data=politeness)
```

would appear to be appropriate.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, yes it does answer my question perfectly, thank you very much!